# Build using Ant Script issue through Netbeans

Tags: ant, netbeans6.8

I am trying to run ANT through shell without importing my projects in NetBeans IDE. It throws following error:

> /trunk/nbproject/build-impl.xml:377: The libs.CopyLibs.classpath
>   property is not set up. This property must point to
>   org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar file which is
>   part of NetBeans IDE installation and is usually located at
>   /java/ant/extra folder. Either open
>   the project in the IDE and make sure CopyLibs library exists or setup
>   the property manually. For example like this:  ant
>   -Dlibs.CopyLibs.classpath=a/path/to/org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar

Is it because my build is NetBeans specific or is it something else?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running ANT in the manner suggested by the error message? Setting the **libs.CopyLibs.classpath** property to point at the missing jar file?

The problem here is that the ANT build generated by Netbeqns is designed to be run within the IDE. When run from the command-line you need to ensure the same environment properties are set.

## Update

To use an environment variable, you could try something like:

```
<property environment="env"/>
<property name="libs.CopyLibs.classpath" value="${env.COPY_LIBS_CLASSPATH}"/>
```

Comment: Yeah..I understand that..I want to know the same that how we can set the environment if we want to run without IDE through shell.

Comment: @user1442170 Don't understand your request.